# d3js - use of d3.drag and d3.pointer

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag

I am fairly new to d3.js and I have a hard time figuring out exactly how to use correctly the d3.drag function.
Then end goal would be to drag the backgroud (along the x axis) of a line chart.

In my code, I call the drag function like this:

```
svg.call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragStarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragEnded));
```

I understand that the "drag" will create an event with event.x and event.y associated with the location of the mouse on the screen.

However, what I fail to do, is to associate that location to the coordinates of my x axis.
I tried using the d3.pointer, but it didn't work:

```
 var x0 = x.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]);
```

d3.pointer returns the same X and Y values as event.x and event.y .

And I think once I will have figured this out I will find a way to solve my backrgound dragging.

Anyone could help me understand how I can use d3.drag in order to drag the background (with the lines moving with it) along the x-axis ? Thank a lot for your help!

Comment: What do you men by "along an x-axis"? Do you want to just drag something along in the horizontal direction? Do you want to change the visible part of the x domain? Please add a [mre] of what you want, and tell us what you expect to see.

Comment: Hello,
I am sorry for the lack of details in my first post.

Comment: Here is an exanple taken on the net that show a little bit what I want to do:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/4tqn7162/1/)
As you can see, the visibal part of the x-domain changes when the graph is dragged. 
I have a hard time figuring out what to do from that example since I am using v6 of d3. 
As for the minimal repoducible example, apart from the code I included in my previous post, I dont really know what to add since I dont really know yet how d3.drag can be used. 
I hope this can help you.. help me! 
Thanks again !